# Positioning Pie Chart DataLabel inside a slice vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am tasked with creating a special graphic(see attachment) @work. I have managed to create this using highcharts [ pie ] but the problem is the positioning of the data-labels. I need the labels to be inside the slice and vertically aligned according to the slice angle on the pie.

Is it possible to do this with highcharts?

The second (bigger graphic) is what I have managed to create so far with highcharts and I am struggling to position the labels as shown on the smaller graphic.

Please help...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248855/rotating-datalabels-in-a-highcharts-pie-chart

Comment: Yes, that is helping a lot. thank you.