# how to achieve the border of pie chart slices in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know nesting is possible in PieChart but Is it possible to build a similar donut chart as shown in the picture? especially the gap between the slices on the outer donut,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can mark all of your data points as `sliced`, set `innerSize` and `borderColor`. For example:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    innerSize: '30%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    data: [{
      y: 23934,
      sliced: true
    }, {
      y: 22503,
      sliced: true
    }, ...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zpr4hygu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie

Rotating data labels thread: [Rotating dataLabels in a Highcharts pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248855/rotating-datalabels-in-a-highcharts-pie-chart)

Comment: The border in your answer and the image is different than the image. In image, it is a gradient, not a plain color

Comment: Hi @Rafay Hassan, You can specify an individual gradient color for each slice: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GradientColorObject Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gqts8ya4/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have updated the question, do you think it is possible in Highchart, that I am unable to join the slices of the same category on the outer donut

Comment: I will answer in your second question thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73452148/is-multi-level-donut-chart-is-possible-in-hightcharts

Comment: As to your second question - please check `sunburst` series type. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ng37ovjm/ Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/sunburst-series