# Hight charts donut chart with different fill color and border color

Tags: highcharts

I have a requirement create a donut chart in using highchart with 0.25% slice fill colot and 0.5% border color and space between slices(borderWidth. When I provide border color. space between slices also filling with border color.

The Requirements

1. Pie chart with colors array
2. 0.25% silce fill color
3. 0.5% slice border color
4. 10px gap between pie slices

[image]

Tried with adding border color and border width but not working.

Comment: Check the following topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430486/how-to-achieve-the-border-of-pie-chart-slices-in-highcharts

Comment: The above one is working when all the slices are nearly equal shares. I have edited the given filddle to see if the shares are different. does not working as expected
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg3j5vwn/)

Comment: According to the following topic https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14123 , this will require workaround solution. I created example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bz8x7tep/